# Удаление элементов в массиве

Tags: массивы, c++

Подскажите что в моем коде не так. Мне нужно удалить из нескольких элементов только три, но моя программа выдает не верный результат.

```
using namespace::std;

int main() 
{ 
    int n, a, b, c; 
    int x[100], m[100];
    cout << " n?.. "; cin >> n;  //количество  элементов
    cout << endl; 
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) 
    { 
        cout << "x[" << k << "] = "; 
        cin >> x[k]; 
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
    {
        cout << endl << " №?.. "; cin >> m[i]; // номера удаляемых элементов
        cout << endl;

        if (m[i] > n) m[i] = n; 
        if (m[i] < 1) m[i] = 1; 
        --m[i]; 
        --n;

        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) 
        { 
            if (k < m[i]) continue; 
            else x[k] = x[k + 1];   
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) cout << x[k] << ' '; 
    }

    getch(); 
}
```

Comment: @slim, приведите пример. 

Что именно Вы  видите на экране, а что ожидаете?

Comment: Ожидаю например: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 и из этого удалить нужно 1-й, 3-й, 4-й элемент и должно получиться 2, 5. А у меня удаляются как-то последовательно новому массиву.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так Вы каждый раз вводите номера в **первоначальном** массиве. А он же меняется при каждом удалении.

В Вашем случае (и только при вводе *последовательно возрастающих* индексов удаляемых элементов) нужно после ввода `m[i]` вычесть из него `i` (т.е. количество **уже удаленных**).

Comment: Спасибо все получилось) Эх и как я такую мелочь упустил(

Comment: avp, а не подскажите как сделать при вводе любых индексов удаляемых элементов?

Comment: Т.е. для произвольного порядка ввода индексов?

--

Если удалять, как у Вас, сразу после ввода, то ничего хорошего в голову не лезет. Из "плохого"  - можно сделать "параллельный" массиву `x[]` массив, скажем `ix[]`, в котором хранить индексы `x`.

При удалении искать заданный номер в `ix[]` и удалять его и соответствующий элемент в `x[]`. НО, такая ерунда мне самому не нравится.

--

Если же сначала ввести **все** индексы удаляемых из `x` элементов (полностью заполнить `m[]`), то все просто. Сортируете `m`, выбрасывая дубликаты и удаляете как и было. Ну, тут можно удалить и за один проход.